How can I recover data from a recovered sqlite database file that has been partly overwritten?
I stupidely deleted a sqlite file that contained some data I wish to recover.
I was able to successfully recover the database file, but it appears to be partially overwritten, however the vast majority of the data I want to recover is still there when I inspect the file.
I have tried .recover in sqlite3 but it did not recover the data. I have tried using the tool undark but it also didn't work. My best bet feels like unpicking the data manually, but I can't find a reference of exactly how to do this. None of the recovery tools I've used have worked either.
The data is in a very simple format, the create table statement is:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  stats (item TEXT UNIQUE, count INT);
I can see the data in the recovered file (opened with vim) is there (it's shopping list data). Here's a snippet:
<86>X^B^]cucumber       <86>W^B^[sachets^G<86>Q^B^Wbread^L®^@b^Ypaneer^LQ^@^U^N<86>U^B%goats cheese^K<86>B^B^_rinse a^G<86>m^B^Wbread^Mý^A<9d>^Upeas^Mý^A<94>#baked beans^Mý^A<84>)chicken breast
<86>i^B^]mint tea^O<86>h^B'chilli flakes^G<86>g^B^Wpolos^Mý^AH#raspberries^Q<86>e^B+cherry tomatoes^N<86>d^B%single cream^M9^@/^_aubergine^M9^@!^[spinach^R<86>a^B-butternut squash
<86>`^B^]oat milk^W<86>_^B7white chocolate chips^Mc^@^N^_mushrooms      <86>]^B^[carrots^M<86>1^B#boy ^Mî^@i/semi skimmed milk^Mî^@S^[carrots
<83>^Z^B^]parsnips^H<83>^W^B^Ycheese^Mî^@/#cauliflower^Mø^@^K^Yapples^Q<83>^S^B+unsalted bu^N<83> ^B%kitchen roll^M<83>^_^B#lemon juice^N4^@
^[c^O<83>"^B^K<83>$^B^_oaty bars^N<83>^^^B%basmati rice^T<82>x^B1first class stamps^O<82>t^B'fine sea salt^NF^@

I have tried opening the file with a hex editor but I can't find out how to get the structured data I need (the count for each of those items).
How can I recover the data from this file? I'm happy to do it manually, it's only ~100 items, but I don't know how to retrieve the integer count value from this file.
